# iphone 4s not scaling but 5,6 and 6 plus are

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am currently creating my images in sketch 3 and using an iPhone 6 sized "art board" (size of the canvas)

exporting my images like:

**size  prefix**

1x --- @1x

2x --- @2x

3x --- @3x

not sure if thats right ^^^

all thoughts and ideas please:) much love

> IPHONE 4s
>   [image]
>
> IPHONE 6
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aspect ratio for 5/6/6+ is different from that of 4S (and older phones).

Since you exported the image created for 5/6/6+, it doesn't look correct on the 3.5 inch screens, because they have a different aspect ratio.

iPhone 4s and older iPhones are 4:3 aspect ratio

iPhone 5 and newer iPhones are 16:9 aspect ratio

Either chop the top & bottom of your 2X images so that its 4:3

or

Set the image as aspect fill.

Comment: What do u mean top bottom ?  And which one do u prefer

Comment: Would this change the quality of the images

Comment: I'm assuming you are setting these images in a full screen sized uiimageview. if so, aspect fill should take care of what you are trying to do. If you are trying to demo this using the Sketch app on iPhone, then you'll have to have the 1X image according to the 4S dimensions (of 4:3 aspect ratio), which is 640x960